# Navigation drawer overlaps the CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-titlebar

The `NavigationDrawer` pops up above the main activity overlapping the `CollapsingToolbar`.This makes it look weird. I want it to come below the `CollapsingToolbar` displaying the title and the action buttons. Also there is one more bug that makes me mad, when the  `NavigationDrawer` closes the title disappears from the action bar. Now this happens only when the `CollapsingToolbar` is in collapsed state. Please help me out on this one.

Main activity file is:-

```
 import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;  
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.defcomm.invento.NavigationDrawerActivity;
 import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class INVENTO extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinator;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsableLayout;
private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
private ViewPager mPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    mCoordinator= (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
    mCollapsableLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mCollapsableLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    nestedScrollView= (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.rvToDoList);
    mCollapsableLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
    mCollapsableLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
    NavigationDrawerActivity drawerFragment= (NavigationDrawerActivity) getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout), toolbar);


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_invento, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

`activity_new.xml` file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.defcomm.invento.INVENTO">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="#3f51b5"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primaryColor"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/index"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="5dp"

            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.defcomm.invento.NavigationDrawerActivity"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
 }
```

My `NavigationDrawer` `Java` file is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;  
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends Fragment {


private ActionBarDrawerToggle mdrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mdrawerLayout;
private boolean mUserLearnedState;
private CoordinatorLayout mcoordinator;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
View containerId;
public static final String file_pref_name = "Testpef";
public static final String KEY_USER_VALUE = "user_learned_drawer";
private boolean mfromSavedInstanceState;

public NavigationDrawerActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedState = Boolean.valueOf(readPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_VALUE, "false"));
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mfromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    //recyclerview= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    return layout;

}


public void setUp(final int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerlayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    mdrawerLayout = drawerlayout;

    containerId = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mdrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerlayout, toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!mUserLearnedState) {
                mUserLearnedState = true;
                saveToPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_VALUE, mUserLearnedState + "");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if (slideOffset < 0.5f) {
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
            }
        }
    };
    if (!mUserLearnedState && !mfromSavedInstanceState) {
        mdrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerId);
    }

    mdrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mdrawerToggle);
    mdrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mdrawerToggle.syncState();

        }
    });

}


public static void saveToPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences(file_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences share = context.getSharedPreferences(file_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return share.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saperated the layout files as per the new Android material design guidelines.That has worked for me.